# Android Device never receives location updates

Tags: android, geolocation

I ran into a peculiar problem today: We need the users geolocation to provide our service and it is working well so far (implementation before the recent Android Location API release, have not updated it yet). We register like this

```
((LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE))
        .requestLocationUpdates((provider == WPS)? 
        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER : LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        minTime, minDist, onChange(ctx, provider)); // onChange create a pending intent
```

and on certain events we call

```
Location gpsLocation = LocMngr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location wpsLocation = LocMngr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

On a HTC One S running on Android 4.0.3 and HTC Sense 4.0 we **never** receive location updates and the last known location returns **null for gps and a 2 day old location for wps**. WIFI, GPS and Mobile Data is turned on, i've tried walking around outside and saw the device trying to get a gps fix, but apparently it did not get one. Other devices have no problem with receiveing location updates from gps or wps using the same code...

This only occurs on this device (it's a test device so bootloader is locked, not rooted or any other funky stuff that might break brick it)

I am at a loss, any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Since we rebooted the device the problem did not occur again, I am still wondering what caused the problem...

**UPDATE 2**

I ran into the same Problem yesterday with a Galaxy Nexus official Android 4.2.2. So this seems to be a problem of Android in general.

Now that apparently nobody knows how to solve this, is there any way to detect when the Location API is not sending any fixes anymore? Apart from checking the timestamp of the lastKnownLocation()?

Comment: Try to use maps application and see how it will look your location.

Comment: Having the same problem with a couple of our apps, so rest assured you're not alone. Never did like Sense... now I know wny! Only came across this bug today so will feed any info I find back into this question. Best of luck finding a solution!

Comment: Just to confirm - I remember having similar issues with my HTC Desire when working on my tracker app. I never solved the problem though, so can't offer advice.